# Interlock mechanism in lateral file cabinet sticks for one drawer (of 4)

Tags: furniture

My metal, lateral file cabinet's interlock mechanism (lock bar) sticks for one of the four drawers. The slider on the side of the drawers have an angle at the end that pushes the bar up when first opened, but for a single drawer, it catches. I tried lithium grease to no effect. However, if I push a flat tool in, the mechanism pops & the drawer opens freely. I just don't want to have to use a tool every time.

Comment: if you provide a picture we might be able to help

Comment: Sounds like something is either worn or bent or misaligned where the interlock mechanism meets the drawer. Without details, it's hard to say more than that...